# Can a GPS receive its signal from within the engine compartment of a vehicle

Tags: gps

I want to place the GPS and GPS antenna inside the engine compartment of a vehicle. Will the device acquire an accurate fix?

Comment: If the engine compartment is open or has a plastic hood - why not.

Comment: The blantanly obvious answer is "no" or "NFW".  However, why ask instead of just trying it?  Put a GPS device on top of the engine, close the hood, wait 10 minutes, and see if it has a fix.  Now imagine if the engine were running and all the associated electrical noise under the hood.  Again, NFW!

Comment: The seams between the hood and the fenders are not electrically contacted, thus RF energy will come through those seams, just like long slot antenna allow much shorter wavelengths to enter easily. Place your GPS under those seams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably not, GPS works with extremely weak EM signals from the GPS satellites. These EM signals cannot pass through metal. So if the hood is metal: no, won't work.

Also, if the engine runs on petrol, it has an ignition. This produces disturbances which will disturb GPS reception.

Even on a diesel which has no ignition there are many parts with active electronics in the engine compartment which will harm GPS reception.

All in all: I think you would be extremely lucky if the GPS worked **at all**.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities you can consider : to place the antenna under the plastic shroud or cover where the wipers mount or extend it up around the windscreen or even have a windscreen with the antenna built-in across the top section - they are so fine now that they are almost invisible...